# Pandas complex GROUP BY using values from two column

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file which has 5820 rows with occurrence of following patterns in `MinP` and `MaxP`

```
| State | MinP |MaxP|
----------------------
| State | 0    |0   |
| State | 0    |1   |
| State | 0    |2   |
| State | 0    |3   |
| State | 1    |1   |
| State | 1    |2   |
| State | 1    |3   |
| State | 1    |4   |
| State | 8    |8   |
...
...
...
| State | 1    |4   |
-----------------------
```

Now I need to group by and count occurrence of each patten

```
| State        | Total State
----------------------
| State1(0,0)  | 30
| State1(0,1)  | 12
| State1(0,2)  | 652
| State1(0,3)  | 1
| State1(1,1)  | 458
| State1(1,2)  | 67
| State1(1,3)  | 200
| State1(1,4)  | 800
| State1(8,8)  | 3600
-----------------------
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas? The following standard `groupby()` only groups the `df` by one field `MinP` but what I need is combination of two fields:

```
df = pd.read_csv("services.csv")
df  =  df.groupby(['MinP'])['MinP'].count()
df .loc['Total State'] = df.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

You can apply columns to tuple and use .value_counts().
Example using dummy data.

Code:

```
data = {
    "State": ["State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State"],
    "MinP": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    "MaxP": [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df = (df[["State", "MinP", "MaxP"]]
      .apply(func=tuple, axis=1)
      .to_frame(name="State")
      .value_counts()
      .reset_index(name="Total State")
      )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           State  Total State
0  (State, 0, 1)            2
1  (State, 0, 0)            1
2  (State, 0, 2)            1
3  (State, 1, 1)            1
4  (State, 1, 2)            1
5  (State, 1, 3)            1
```